# how to convert decimal to binary in c++

Tags: c++

I have a method to convert dec to bin

```
QList<bool> widgetInput::decToBin(int number)
{
        int remainder;
        QList<bool> result;
        if(number <= 1) {
            result << number;
            return result;
        }

        remainder = number%2;
        decToBin(number >> 1);
        result << remainder;


}
```

but unfortunately this method only holds one element in list .
but when I replace the "result << number" with "cout << number"
it will work.
could you please help me and let me know where is my exact problem?

regards.

Comment: why are you trying to do this recursively?

Comment: `do { result << number & 1 } while (number>>=1); return result;` (You wanted to know where the problem was, so this is not really an answer, which is why it is a comment)

Comment: The parameter `number` is already represented in the program in binary, and the code does not seem to make any reference to decimal. So I was curious about why the name of your function involves decimal, and why you do not just provide what you need by encapsulating the number in a class that accesses whichever bits you need. Maybe I missed something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On each recursive step, you are creating a new QList result; which is local to that step, then inserting the remainder into it. You don't need recursion (and in general it should be avoided when iteration will do):

```
QList<bool> result;

while(number > 0) {
  result << number%2;
  number /=2;
}

// Edited to add: Just realized you would also have to reverse QList here.
//  Depends on it's interface.

return result;
```

or better yet, just use a standard container:

```
bitset<sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT> bs(number);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're very close, but you will need to make one modification:

```
    remainder = number%2;
    result << remainder << decToBin(number >> 1);
    return result;
```

I'm not sure exactly how QList works, but the above is intended to append the result of `decToBin()` after the `remainder` in the result. You may need to modify this slightly to make it work.

The result will then contain the binary representation of the number, in "reverse" order (with the least significant bit in the first position of the list).

Answer (score 1):

First of all why make it recursive?

As pointed by others, the `result` variable is local, so it "resets" every time the method is called.

Because computers are binary beasts, I'd change to something like this:

```
QList<bool> widgetInput::decToBin(int number) 
{ 
    QList<bool> result = new QList<bool>(); 
    while (number)
    {
       result.Add(number & 1);
       number = number >> 1;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: QList<bool> result; will do. No need for the C# verbosity :)

Answer (score 0):

`QList<bool> result;` is a local variable so there can be only values inserted in this method call. And it is only one.

There are few solutions:

- Add QList like a method parameter and after that if will work fine
- Or append returned value from recursive calls to your list

But these solutions have reverse order so you can choose what is better for you.

And by the way, you are missing return value at the end of the method. So compiler should announce a warning.

Answer (score 0):

There is a more generic iterative solution (that doesn't need Qt):

NB1: You can ignore the "byte completion" part as well as the "#include ". It is just aimed at completing the string with zeros to always get a mutiple of 8 bits...

NB2: Utils is the name of the class where those functions are implemented... I was told that a reverse function already exists in the standard library... haven't tried yet.

NB3: If you don't reverse the string, the little endian will come first... so the normal case is littleEndianFirst = false

```
#include <string>
#include <math.h>

    static std::string decToBin(int number, bool littleEndianFirst)
    {
        std::string result = "";
        do
        {
            ((number & 1) == 0) ? result += "0" : result += "1";
            number >>= 1;
        } while(number);

        if(!littleEndianFirst)
        {
            result = Utils::reverse(result);
        }

        // byte completion
        unsigned int completeByteLength = (ceil(result.length()/8.0))*8;
        while(result.length() < completeByteLength)
        {
            littleEndianFirst ? result += "0" : result = "0" + result;
        }

        return result;
    }

    static std::string reverse(std::string to_reverse){
        std::string result;
        for (int i = to_reverse.length()-1; i >=0 ; i--)
            result += to_reverse[i];
        return result;
    }
```